# Prestashop AJAX not work when Friendly URL is off

Tags: jquery, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a custom module for prestashop there are some AJAX requests there. AJAX request is work fine when  Friendly URL is On but when it off it shows 404 error. AJAX request is going to controller file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{$base_url|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}module/mymodule/ShippingOptions",
    type: 'post',
    data: 'ajax=true&selectDate=' + selectDate ,
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

`ShippingOptions` is the controller file. 
How to change this URL to work both friendly URL on and off?
this is prestashop 1.6

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ajax calls you can use the following code which works regardless of friendly urls or not.

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUri,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        ajax       : true,
        selectDate : selectDate,
        module     : 'myModule',
        fc         : 'module',
        controller : 'ShippingOptions'
    },
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your Ajax request is using the friendly url syntax. You should get the url with:

```
{$link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'ShippingOptions')|escape:'html'}
```

Comment: `$link->getModuleLink` can call this in view .tpl file ?

Comment: yes, that is for usage in .tpl files. you can compare with the official modules, for example: bankwire\views\templates\front\payment_execution.tpl

Comment: This works fine but it make ajax url as below
`http://urbit.dev/index.php?fc=module&amp;module=mymodule&amp;controller=ShippingOptions&amp;id_lang=1`
is there any way to encode `&amp` to & ?

Comment: If you examine the code on the official code, it will generate with &amp; also. not sure it's the |escape:'html' or from the getModuleLink, haven't tested. Also you can pass additional parameters getModuleLink($module, $controller = 'default', array $params = array(), $ssl = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, $relative_protocol = false)